# signOut() method dont work with a session opened with oauth google provider on supabase with flutter

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-flutter

Im trying signout with method auth.signOut() with a session of google signin with method signInWithOAuth() but the session after a hot restart stay opened with google provider

Method signin

```
  Future authenticationUserWithGoogleFromApi() async {
try {
  final response = await clientSupabase.auth.signInWithOAuth(
    Provider.google,
    redirectTo: SupabaseCredentials.myAuthRedirectUri,
  );
  return response;
} on Failure catch (e) {
  throw Failure(e.message);
}
```

}

signout metohd

```
  Future signOutFromApi() async {
try {
  await clientSupabase.auth.signOut();
} on AuthException catch (e) {
  throw Failure(e.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: You just have the deep link being cached on your debug device. Try it on a production build, and this should not happen. Also, native Google login is recommended for iOS and Android apps. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-google?platform=flutter

Comment: yes, its is the solution